# How can I prove $M+t$ is a hyperplane if $M$ is a maximal subspace

Tags: affine-geometry, affine-varieties, hyperspace

Let $M$ be a non-empty proper subset of a vector space $X$ over $\mathbb R$ and $t$ belongs to $X$, then $M$ is a maximal subspace if and only if $t+M$ is a hyperplane and $t$ belongs to $t+M$.